# What does "entrust a character" mean in the Supreme Court's gay marriage judgment?

Tags: meaning, translation, legalese

I'm translating the Obergefell v. Hodges judgment into another language. As a non-native speaker, I really struggled with this sentence:

> The nature of injustice is that we may not always see it in our own
>   times. The generations that wrote and ratified the Bill of Rights and
>   the Fourteenth Amendment did not presume to know the extent of freedom
>   in all of its dimensions, and so they **entrusted to future
>   generations a character** protecting the right of all persons to enjoy
>   liberty as we learn its meaning.

What does "entrust a character" mean here? I know that "entrust" means assigning responsibility, but what does "character" mean? A distinctive mental quality? How do you *entrust* that to someone?

Thank you so much!

Comment: I would surmise that this refers to "character" in the sense of "moral excellence and firmness".

Comment: @HotLicks- I up-voted your comment and hope that you will expand on it to form a proper answer to this question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is founded on a misreading of (or typographical error in)  the text.

Comment: @Jim Thanks so much for pointing this out! Everything makes sense now... Sorry about not googling before I asked the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be a typo.

> The generations that wrote and ratified the Bill of Rights and the Fourteenth Amendment did not presume to know the extent of freedom in all of its dimensions, and so they entrusted to future generations a ***charter*** protecting the right of all persons to enjoy liberty as we learn its meaning.

[The U.S. Supreme Court Decision on Marriage Equality](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=WyN2CgAAQBAJ&pg=PT23&dq=%22protecting+the+right+of+all+persons+to+enjoy+liberty+as+we+learn+its+meaning.+when%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNlbqIi-LJAhUk6aYKHYdJBgwQ6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=%22protecting%20the%20right%20of%20all%20persons%20to%20enjoy%20liberty%20as%20we%20learn%20its%20meaning.%20when%22&f=false)

Comment: Ah thanks so much! I got the text from a reliable source, but it seems like they got it wrong... Thanks again! Makes so much more sense now.